# Smarthost percentage of mail on Exim4

Tags: exim, smarthost

I'm transitioning mailing of a sizeable number of mails (maybe 1m/day) to another host.  I want to warm up the new host gradually over a month rather than suddenly start sending through it and appear to be a spammer.

Is there any way to tell exim to smarthost only a fraction of the emails?  That way I could start off smarthosting through my old host, and gradually ramp up the mail that goes out directly from the new host.

Comment: You could use a DNS name for the smarthost and add 9 A records for the old IP and 1 A record for the new IP for a 9/1 split of the load. Then gradually change the number of A records of each.

Comment: Sneaky.  I hadn't thought of that, and I like it.

Comment: Exim have variables that can be tested during routing. Say, you assign some random value to the acl_m_prob variable and then if it lower than threshold, submit it via new_smarthost, and via old_smarthost else.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'd want to do, but it would be useful to have an example config.